# Erro nullpointer ao fazer consulta no banco com parâmetro

Tags: java, sql, oracle, spring

Quando executo a query abaixo tenho um erro de nullPointer.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM x WHERE USER_NAME = :name", nativeQuery = true)
DataBaseCobilling findByCdIdent(@Param("name") String name);
```

Porem quando executo essa funciona :

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM x WHERE USER_NAME = 'WESLEY BANDEIRA LIMA'", nativeQuery = true)
 * DataBaseCobilling getByUserName();
```

Estou passando o mesmo nome como parâmetro, quando faço por parâmetro da erro quando executo a query direto funciona.

Qual poderia ser o erro  ?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at br.com.oiinternet.oitestautomation.sga.page.PaymentCobillingPage.fillDddAndCollectionPhone(PaymentCobillingPage.java:66)
at br.com.oiinternet.oitestautomation.sga.test.PurchaseCobillingTest.purchasePlanCobilling(PurchaseCobillingTest.java:38)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: Está utilizando algum framework? em qual parte do código da o erro? consegue informar a causa do erro?

Comment: O que é o "*" no retorno do segundo método?

Comment: @MurilloGoulart o * foi a mais pode ignorar,

Comment: @ElyelRubensdaRosa estou usando Spring,

Comment: Não teria que concatenar as aspas simples antes de inserir a variável de nome? `'<minha_variavel>'`

Comment: Esta parte do código aparenta estar correta, verifique se a importação esta correta

       import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

Answer (score 0):

Isso é um bug do **Spring Data JPA** e foi corrigido na versão **1.3.4**.

Atualize a versão via **Maven** e verifique se o erro será corrigido.